# mono for android. Home screen widget

Tags: android-widget, xamarin.android

Do you know any examples, screencasts that document how to develop an home screen widget on "mono for android" ?

I would like to develop a tiny home screen view and I'm searching for the proper way to code it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Xamarin has a sample widget project available in [their samples on GitHub](https://github.com/xamarin/monodroid-samples/tree/master/SimpleWidget)